# filter pytrends data and also get data and country columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pulling data from google trends ,encountering some issues:

code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrensReq
pytrends=TrendReq()
kw_list= ['Solar power','Starlink']
df1=pytrends.build(kw_list,timeframe='today 100-w',geo='US','UK')
df1=pytrends.interest_by_region(),pytrends.interest_over_time()
df1.to_excel(r'e:\google trends\putout.xlsx')

    i want data for 2 regions- US and UK .but it is not working .
    also i want data for past 100 weeks from today's date.I checked on google to see what is the syntax
    for looking in past weeks but no help.
    Also if i use " pytrends.interest_by_region(),pytrends.interest_over_time()", i get data like:
     solar power       Starlink
date

But country column is not included.I have used pytrends.interest_by_region() but it is not coming in my dataframe.

Expected output:
                     solar power       Starlink    
country date                                   
US      2021-05-01    5                   4
UK      2021-05-01    4                   5  

....so on. Let me know how to get both country and date in the dataset.
```

and

And finally export it to csv or excel file.

Comment: There seem to be some errors in the code. The third argument in pytrends.build should be a list. Also, you are trying to import 'TrensReq' which is probably wrong. Please put a working code snippet in your question.

Comment: @DSteman,  If i remove timeframe and geo it is working fine and also i want date and country both how to do this

Comment: Then remove the geo argument from the code in the question.

Comment: I getting this error with your code :ImportError: cannot import name 'TrensReq' from 'pytrends.request'

Comment: @Dsteman, add pytrends=TrendReq() at third line from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, this will give result in required format:

```
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
kw_list= ['Solar power','Starlink']
l = []
for i in ['US','GB']:
    pytrends=TrendReq()
    pytrends.build_payload(kw_list,timeframe='today 3-m',geo=i)
    df=pytrends.interest_over_time()
    df['country']=i
    l.append(df.reset_index())
df1 = pd.concat(l)
df1.to_excel(r'e:\google trends\putout.xlsx')
```

Following changes I did in your current code:

1. For timeframe, pytrends provide only few options and "today 100-w" is not one of them

   - Current Time Minus Time Pattern:

     - By Month: '**today #-m**' where # is the number of months from that date to pull data for, ***only work for 1, 2, 3 months***
     - Daily: '**now #-d**' where # is the number of days from that date to pull data for,
       **only work for 1, 7 days**
     - Hourly: '**now #-H**' where # is the number of hours from that date to pull data for, **only work for 1, 4 hours**

   I suggest for specific dates, use 'YYYY-MM-DD YYYY-MM-DD' example '2016-12-14 2017-01-25'
2. You can not provide list to geo parameter, it should be string of country code, For United kingdom the code is 'GB'(Refer this link: [Country json](https://www.gstatic.com/charts/regioncoder/0/geocodes/countries_en.js), This will give you the json of all google trends supported countries and its respective codes)